# "Property ** is used before its initialization in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I developed sample class as follows. I set private variables as follows but it returned following errors.

`"Property 'shopCode' is used before its initialization."`

I couldn't find where shopCode is used before initialization.

```
export class getIrohaTransaction {

private shopCode:string;
private TransactionId:string;

constructor(shopCode:string,TransactionId:string) {
    this.shopCode = shopCode;
    this.TransactionId = TransactionId;
}

private requestParam = {
    request: {
        apiCommonRequestHeader: {
            requestId:12345,
            serviceType: '01',
            useInterface: '3',
            shopCode: this.shopCode,
            accessInfo: {
                accessInfo1: 'PRICING',
                accessInfo2: this.shopCode,
                accessInfo3: this.shopCode,
                accessIpAddress: "127.0.0.1",
            },
        },
        transactionSearchCondition: {
            transactionid: this.TransactionId,
        },
        },
}

const result = await client.searchTransactionAsync(requestParam)
}
```

I wonder what is the root cause of this. if someone has opinion,please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Which line of code is identified by the error?

Answer (score 2):

Try this `private shopCode:string = "";`

because in `reuqestParam` object you are using it before initialisation.

So, either initialise it while declaring or set `strictPropertyInitialisation:false` in `tsconfig.json`

Comment: thank you for comment, in my code where is initialization done .. ? I guess it is initialized by `constructor` so that after that initialization,  shopCode is used in `requestParam` . I still couldn't understand where is the initialization done.. thanks !

Comment: Variable or object declared outside the function/constructor will initialise first. Here sequence doesn't matter

Comment: I think you need to move code lines below after the closure of constructor in a separate function and call that function from constructor after initialisation of `shopCode` and `noTransactionaId`

Comment: thanks.. so why call function from constructor is suitable for this case... ? I couldn't understand the merit of this. thanks !

Comment: Correction: it's `strictPropertyInitialization`.